# What shape is the split-complex projective line?

Tags: projective-geometry, split-complex-numbers

I'm aware that the complex projective line is a sphere, the Riemann sphere, and the dual projective line is a cylinder; but I can't find anything mentioning what shape the split-complex projective line would be. I probably could figure it out for myself, of course, but I'm surprised that it doesn't come up in searching.

Comment: It's probably not that straightforward, since it's not a field. What definition of projective line would you propose?

Comment: Duals aren't a field either, but they have a projective line. The definition is rather standard, isn't it? Ordered pairs (x,y) together with an equivalence relation ~ where for all invertible elements n you have (x,y) ~ (xn,yn).

Comment: It's a hyperboloid of one sheet, see for example the third paragraph [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projective_line_over_a_ring#Over_topological_rings). More generally, if I'm not mistaken the geometry of the projective line over the ring $\mathbb{R}[j]/(j^2-t)$ is the surface of revolution of the curve $|x+yj|^2=x^2-ty^2=1$ around the $y$-axis.

Comment: Thanks! I somehow never found that. If you could write that up as a full answer (and if possible include references to why that thing about surfaces of revolution is true) that would be great!